# USING SCOPE "team" not working in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I try `USING SCOPE` in SQOL to return all accounts assigned to account team.

I took a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_using_scope.htm) and wrote the following in an Apex Class:

`SELECT Name,Phone,Site,Type FROM Account USING SCOPE team`

But I don't get correct results. Please see follow image:

Salesforce Standard "My Account Team" List View

[image]

My debug result in Developer Console

[image]

Did I misunderstand this documentation? Where I can find correct scope value?

Comment: have you taken a look at your list view's actual filters (click the funnel icon)? The list view is called `My Account Team`, but anyone with access can change the filter criteria.

Comment: if you are owner of the recs then you are also by default on the accountTeam